# How to deal with multiple overlaps in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I've been fighting this for quite a long time and everytime I think I got it, I got it wrong actually.

### What's the trouble

See picture below. As a result of line buffers I got overlaps that need to be removed on buffer ends. I'm looking for a way to tell PostGIS which overlaps should be differed from which buffer. I ended up with topological incorrect polygons several times.

If you wish, grab the [table dump](https://gist.github.com/zimmicz/f19d5721fa8a4d650859).

[image]

I get all the overlaps with this query:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, ST_Union(b.geom)))).geom geom
        FROM test a, test b
        WHERE a.geom && b.geom
            AND ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
            AND NOT ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom)
        GROUP BY a.geom
```

No idea how to proceed.

**UPDATE**
I need to remove overlaps so buffers face each other just fine with no white space. E.g. if two buffers overlap, the overlapping portion of space should be removed just from the one of those two.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove all overlaps leaving white space?

Comment: @artwork21 question updated

Comment: Have you looked at using the v.clean Grass method via QGIS Processing (menu)>Commander (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.clean.html)?

Comment: I have. It gives erroneous results and invalid geometries in some cases and cannot be considered robust.

Answer (score 1):

My dirty brute force solution

```
DO $$
DECLARE r input;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM input
      LOOP

         IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM output WHERE output.wkb_geometry && r.wkb_geometry)
            THEN
            r.wkb_geometry := ST_Multi(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Difference(r.wkb_geometry, ST_Union(output.wkb_geometry)), 3))
            FROM output
            WHERE output.wkb_geometry && r.wkb_geometry;
         END IF;

         INSERT INTO output values(r.*);
      END LOOP;
END $$
```

~

An there is a link 
https://boundlessgeo.com/2014/10/postgis-training-creating-overlays/
for pretty solution by Paul Ramsey.